# Why isn't $V_\kappa$ a model of Paul Bernays' reflection principle when $\kappa$ is inaccessible?

Tags: set-theory

We work in KM with two kinds of variables. Let PB (Paul Bernays' Reflection) be the following schema:

$$\psi (\vec x_n, \vec Y_n) \rightarrow \exists t (t \text{ is a transitive set} \land [\psi (\vec x, \vec{Y_n\cap t)}]^t)$$
where $\vec x_n$ are the set parameters and $\vec Y_n$ are the class parameters (if there is any). $[\psi (\vec x, \vec{Y_n\cap t)}]^t$ is the result of (i) repalcing every occurence of $Y_n$ with $Y_n \cap t$ and then (ii) restricting all first-order quantifiers to $t$ and all second-order quantifiers to subsets of $t$.

Let $\kappa$ be inaccessible. Here is an attempt to show that PB is satisfied in  $<V_\kappa, V_{\kappa+1}, \in>$. We show it by induction.

Base case: Suppose  $<V_\kappa, V_{\kappa+1}, \in> \models \psi (x, Y)$ and $\psi (x, Y)$ only contains first-order quantifiers. We take $Y$ to be a 1-place predicate and we know that there will be some $<V_\alpha, V_\alpha \cap Y, \in>$ which is a elementary submodel of $<V_\kappa,\ Y, \in>$. So, there is some transitive set in $V_\kappa$ that reflects $\psi(x, Y\cap t)$.

Induction Step: Suppose  $<V_\kappa, V_{\kappa+1}, \in> \models \psi (x, Y)$ and $\psi (x, Y)$ is of the form $\exists Z \phi (Z, x, Y)$. Then there is some $X \subseteq V_\kappa$ such that $<V_\kappa, V_{\kappa+1}, \in> \models \phi (X, x, Y)$. By induction hypothesis, there is some transitive set $t \in V_\kappa$ such that $(\phi (X\cap t, x, Y \cap t))^t$. So $\exists Z \subseteq t [\phi (Z, x, Y \cap t)]^t$, which is $[\psi (x, Y\cap t)]^t$.

My question: since we know that PB is much stronger than an inaccessible, where does this argument go wrong?

Comment: Paul Bernays has an s on the end of his name, so the apostrophe should come after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your induction step isn't complete: what about sentences of the form $\forall Z\phi(Z,x,Y)$? (And Boolean combinations, but that's less interesting.) Indeed, it's exactly here that we see the possible failure of the reflection principle:

Let $\kappa$ be the *least* inaccessible. Then $(V_\kappa,V_{\kappa+1},\in)$ satisfies "The universe of sets is inaccessible," phrased as follows:

- There is no *set* $x$ and *class function* $F$ with domain $x$ such that the range of $F$ is cofinal in the ordinals, and
- For every *set* $x$ there is a *set* $y$ such that every *subclass* $A$ of $x$ is in fact (coextensional with) a *set* in $y$.

Note that this is $\Pi^1_1$ when optimally expressed - that is, just beyond where your argument reaches. And indeed it's a counterexample to the reflection principle:  if $t\in V_\kappa$ is transitive, then $(t, \mathcal{P}(t), \in)$ cannot satisfy this sentence since $\kappa$ is the least inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was thinking we take universal quantifiers as non-primitive symbols. I guess the problem then would be that $\neg \phi$ may not be reflected.